# Look cell addres in excel

Tags: excel, formula

Sorry for my bad english,

I have tables like these:

[image: enter image description]

I need the Sup column return S1,S2,S3 automatic according the cheapest column. I've use any reff formula and nothing match what I need. Thanks for helps

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I came up with:

```
=IF(E2=D2,D$1,IF(E2=C2,C$1,IF(E2=B2,B$1,"error")))
```

Results:

[image]

Comment: Haapy to help. If this answer helped, accepting it as correct would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In F2 and copied down to suit:

```
=INDEX(B$1:D$1,MATCH(MIN(B2:D2),B2:D2,0))
```

Will return the first (L to R) instance of the minimum value where more than one.

Comment: Its more simpler...I add small function to your formula like this:=INDEX($F$4:$N$4;MATCH(SMALL(F7:N7;COUNTIF(F7:N7;0)+1);F7:N7;0)) to avoid 0...big thanks...